# gitlab ci how to trigger a job if only a specific file changes and no others

Tags: gitlab-ci

- I'm using `playwright` to build end to end tests.  I can write a rule that runs the test script if the test script file was changed.
- I want to build a rule sequence that doesn't run any of the other jobs (scan, build, deploy, etc.) on a commit if the test script was the only file that changed
- I also want rules that run the scan, build, deploy, etc. jobs AND the end-to-end test if the test script file and another other file in the repo has changed
- If tried everything I can think of. The following does not work

```yaml
rules:
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $INTEGRATION_BRANCH)
      changes:
        - ! tests/playwright/*

    # Keep integration related jobs from running if only a playwright file changed
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $INTEGRATION_BRANCH) && ($CI_JOB_NAME != "Integration Verification")
      changes:
        - tests/playwright/*
      when: never
  
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $INTEGRATION_BRANCH)

    # Make sure we're not running a job intended for the integration branch
    - if: ($CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
      when: never
```